# PHP echo code from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database set up to store user input and it then displays what they put on the page.

```
$input = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(addslashes($_POST["input"])));
//Later on
echo '<div>'.$input.'</div>';
```

I went to the textarea and typed in some basic php code `"<?php echo 'blahblah'; ?>,"` and it submitted to the database normally, but the homepage doesn't display any of it. No 'blahblah,' no tags. I want it to display the entire `"<?php echo 'blahblah'; ?>"` so people can post whatever they want.

Comment: 1) start using [prepared statements and bound parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead of whatever that thing is your are currently using. 2) use `htmlspecialchars()` to display the data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
echo '<div>'.htmlentities($input).'</div>';
```

It converts special characters like < and > to html entities so they are displayed correctly in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping needs to be appropriate for its context.

- When inserting into the database, use `mysql_real_escape_string` (or migrate to the newer `mysqli_real_escape_string`, or to PDO) or read up on parameterized queries (AKA prepared statements).
- When displaying in HTML, use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`.

Never use both in one go, because you will get in a mess, and never use `stripslashes(addslashes(...))`, because that makes no sense.